# Array Push only pushing last value of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, for-loop

I want to update array in object for each employeeID.
My "selected" array has the employeeID's to add.
The function adds the same time and jobs for all employees but after each iteration all the emplyeeIDs are the last employeeID that was pushed.

```
selected = [ "01PILGAR", "01DERREX", "01SANJAC" ]

updatePersonnelTime() {
        console.log("updatePersonnelTime", this.time);
        var newtime = this.time;
        newtime.controlDateTime = new Date();
        if(!this.currentJob.time){
            this.currentJob.time = [];
        }
        for (let i=0; i < this.selected.length; i++){
            newtime.employeeID = this.selected[i];
            console.log('this.selected[i]: ', this.selected[i]);
            
            this.currentJob.time.push(newtime); 
            console.log('this.time: ', this.currentJob);
            
        }
        this.updateJob();
        this.timeRows = this.currentJob.time
        
    },
```

This will add three time information to the array with all as the employeeID as "01SANJAC"
When I look at each push the employeeID shows each item from the array being pushed.

Why is the final array have all items with the last employeeID value?

final array =

```
    [ 
{ "task": "1000", "inout": { "label": "In", "value": 1 }, "time": "08:00", "detailNotes": "time", "officeNotes": "office time", "controlDateTime": "2021-09-17T14:54:13.371Z", "employeeID": "01SANJAC" }, 
{ "task": "1000", "inout": { "label": "In", "value": 1 }, "time": "08:00", "detailNotes": "time", "officeNotes": "office time", "controlDateTime": "2021-09-17T14:54:13.371Z", "employeeID": "01SANJAC" }, 
{ "task": "1000", "inout": { "label": "In", "value": 1 }, "time": "08:00", "detailNotes": "time", "officeNotes": "office time", "controlDateTime": "2021-09-17T14:54:13.371Z", "employeeID": "01SANJAC" } 
]
```

This is what solved it for me:

```
updatePersonnelTime() {
        console.log("updatePersonnelTime", this.time);
        var newtime = this.time;
        newtime.controlDateTime = new Date();
        if(!this.currentJob.time){
            this.currentJob.time = [];
        }
        for (let i=0; i < this.selected.length; i++){
            newtime.employeeID = this.selected[i];
            console.log('this.selected[i]: ', this.selected[i]);
            
// added 'Object.assign in the push
            this.currentJob.time.push(Object.assign({}, newtime)); 
            console.log('this.time: ', this.currentJob);
            
        }
        this.updateJob();
        this.timeRows = this.currentJob.time
        
    },
```

Comment: You're pushing the same object over and over again. The calls to `.push()` do not make copies.

Comment: yes the same object with the employeeID changed. How do i push this properly?

Comment: You need to make a *copy* of the object at some point.

Comment: I see the copying objects post and still not sure how to use in saving my array??

Comment: Make a copy of the original object, set its employee id, push it.

Comment: Since this post has been reopened, please take the edit you made to your question which contains an answer and move it to an actual answer post. That way people will know that your question has an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the .push i used "Object.assign({}, '')
This works for me.

```
updatePersonnelTime() {
    console.log("updatePersonnelTime", this.time);
    var newtime = this.time;
    newtime.controlDateTime = new Date();
    if(!this.currentJob.time){
        this.currentJob.time = [];
    }
    for (let i=0; i < this.selected.length; i++){
        newtime.employeeID = this.selected[i];
        console.log('this.selected[i]: ', this.selected[i]);
        
// added 'Object.assign in the push
        this.currentJob.time.push(Object.assign({}, newtime)); 
        console.log('this.time: ', this.currentJob);
        
    }
    this.updateJob();
    this.timeRows = this.currentJob.time
    
},
```